# How to fix 'recursion error' when pickling Pyomo Expressions

Tags: python, pickle, pyomo

I haven't had trouble with pickling a Pyomo model before, but now a recursion error is being raised when trying to pickle Expressions.

Interestingly, the error can be avoided in the example below via a couple of ways:

- by removing the "mutable" flag from the parameter
- by reducing the size of the set to a very small value, to e.g. range(0, 10)

...but I don't know why these would fix the error, nor are they workable solutions for the actual optimization model I am trying to pickle.

**The following example** generates the error from the pickling of just a single Expression.
(I am using pyomo=5.6.2, cloudpickle=0.6.1, and python=3.7.4)

```py
import cloudpickle
import pyomo.environ as pyo

test_model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

# A set is added.
set_elements = list(range(0, 500))
test_model.my_set = pyo.Set(initialize=set_elements)

# A parameter is added.
param_values = dict()
for e in set_elements:
    param_values[e] = 1
test_model.my_param = pyo.Param(test_model.my_set, initialize=param_values, mutable=True)

# An expression is added.
def calculation_rule(mdl):
    return sum(mdl.my_param[e] for e in mdl.my_set)
test_model.calculation_expr = pyo.Expression(rule=calculation_rule)

# We attempt to pickle the expression.
pickle_str = cloudpickle.dumps(test_model.calculation_expr)
```

The last line of the above code raises the following exception:

`PicklingError: Could not pickle object as excessively deep recursion required.`

**QUESTION:** Do I need to modify the way the Expression is written in order to pickle the model, or should I save the model using something other than Cloudpickle?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Seems like an issue related to Python 3.7. When I run your example using Python 3.6 it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One fix is to use Pyomo's `quicksum` instead of Python's `sum`. It leads to more compact expression trees and seems to fix the recursion issue you're seeing:

```
# An expression is added.
def calculation_rule(mdl):
    return pyo.quicksum(mdl.my_param[e] for e in mdl.my_set)
test_model.calculation_expr = pyo.Expression(rule=calculation_rule)
```

Documentation [here](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library_reference/expressions/building.html#pyomo.core.util.quicksum).

Comment: Thanks @BethanyNicholson. I haven't used pyo.quicksum before. Do you know if the quicksum method is generally a good alternative to the built-in sum method when terms in the generator collapse to numeric scalars?  For instance, for something like: `sum(mdl.param1 * mdl.param2 + mdl.param3 for...)` or `sum(mdl.param1 if mdl.param1>10 else 0 for ...)`, is quicksum still appropriate?  Or do I need to be especially careful when converting sums to quicksums?

Comment: I just did a quick test of this and it looks like `quicksum` does what you would expect when the inputs are all scalar values, it reduces them down to a single value. I did a few other tests and couldn't find any cases where `quicksum` couldn't be used in place of `sum` but I'd still recommend asking about `quicksum` caveats on the Pyomo forum. Some of the other Pyomo developers would be able to provide more insight.